# Behavior of future.get with 0 timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, future

Can anyone point me to some documentation that makes clear that a 'Future.get` with a timeout of 0 will not wait?

The API docs for `java.util.concurrent.Future` does not make explicit the behavior of `future.get(0, unit)`. Standing on its own, the statement "Waits if necessary for at most the given time..." implies this invocation will not wait at all, but given the long-standing behavior of `Object.wait(0)` (infinite wait), I'm nervous to depend on a "no wait" behavior of `future.get(0, unit)`

Scanning the source of some JDK-provided classes (viz. `FutureTask`) I see that this particular implementation of `Future` does not wait when the timeout is 0.

I'd like to be able to say

```
   long timeout = Math.max(until - now, 0);
   return future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

but I'm nervous about a Future implementing that as an infinite wait, so instead, I've explicitly coded it the way I would expect it to work:

```
   long timeout = Math.max(until - now, 0);
   if(timeout > 0 || future.isDone()){
      return future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   } else {
      throw TimeoutException();
   }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time…

Waiting for *at most* zero time units is not waiting at all. That's not an implicit hint, it's an explicit guarantee.

Comment: Granted. I thought that this difference in semantics from `Object.wait(long)` would have warranted some explicit distinction made in the docs. Even `Object.wait` at first seems to guarantee no wait "`timeout` - the maximum time to wait in milliseconds" but then backpedals and says "If `timeout` is zero, however, then real time is not taken into consideration and the thread simply waits until notified."

Answer (score 9):

> Can anyone point me to some documentation that makes clear that a 'Future.get` with a timeout of 0 will not wait?

I can point you at some code if that helps.  Looking into `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` and then on to `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` I see the following loop which I've pared down to show the relavent bits:

```
private boolean doAcquireSharedNanos(int arg, long nanosTimeout) {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (;;) {
        ...
        if (nanosTimeout <= 0) {
            cancelAcquire(node);
            return false;
        }
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        nanosTimeout -= now - lastTime;
    }
```

This means that if `nanosTimeout` is 0 (which it will be if you pass in 0 to get) then it will try to acquire the future once and then timeout and return false.

If it makes you feel any better, you can set your timeout to be 1 nanosecond.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the code I had reviewed during my own research.