# Are negative timeouts safe with Future.get(long, TimeUnit)?

Tags: java, specifications, java.util.concurrent

Is it safe to supply a negative timeout to `java.util.concurrent.Future.get(long, TimeUnit)`? The documentation says

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.

Does this imply that it will work with negative values, or does this statement only cover the non-negative cases? The behaviour I would expect would be to return the result if it is available or timeout immediately otherwise. This situation may occur, if we want to calculate the timeout for an absolute point in time and this has already passed. Of course I can use `max{timeout, 0}`, but is this really necessary? Tests in my enviroment showed it worked, but is this guaranteed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332904/behavior-of-future-get-with-0-timeout states that this should be the case for a 0 timeout.

Or to put the question in other words:
Assume the result of the `Future` is available. Would an implementation of `Future` be non compliant, if `get(long, TimeUnit)` called with a negative timeout would do something else than returning this result?

Comment: `Future` is an interface, so you han hardly get any guarantees there. The bottom answer to the question you link to seems to show that negative values are treated the same way as 0 in the case of `FuteureTask`.

Comment: But being an interface does not mean that is has no guaranteed behaviour. Implementations then have to comply with this documented behaviour. I am not sure of the interpretation of the answer in the linked question also cover negative cases.

Comment: Yes, it does. You would expect any implementer to follow the expected behaviour, but the author of the interface can hardly guarantee it.

Comment: Yes, but then this implementation would be non compliant. I added this alternative formulation to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to wait "at most" some time; the only theoretical guarantee is that the wait time will be *no less* than some number. This is in fact specified in the JLS. Therefore the wording must be read as follows:

> Let *t* be the given time to wait, and let *u* be the time this method actually spent before returning control to the caller. If and only if *u* < *t*, the return value of the method call is guaranteed to be the return value of the Future.

Given the above, a negative *t* is fully in order and all values <= 0 should behave exactly the same.

Still, an implementation could conceivably throw an exception for a negative wait time and have a weak excuse for doing so. If your code ever failed due to such an exception, you could start a hot dispute with the authors of said `Future` implementation. If that ever happened, there is really nothing an answer on Stack Overflow can do to prevent it.

If you subsequently went to court to settle the responsibility for damages, and are interested in the outcome of such a lawsuit, then I believe that concern is beyond the realms of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sure that in practice this probably would work, but my question is rather if this actually is required from the specs? This is actually some kind of language and spec lawyer question. I am not sure if my reading is the intended one in this case. People more familar with these kind of specs may have a clearer view of what this sentence means.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` was one possibly compliant behaviour I was thinking of. Based on your prediction of what happens if someone would really implement it differently, I would say that the spec might be ambiguous in a theoretical sense, but clear enough for practical purposes.

Comment: I am not so much interested in going to court but trying to avoid relying on undefined behaviour. I think that your answer makes it clear, that the behaviour for negative values can validly inferred from the statement.